# How to reuse json in RAML example

Tags: json, raml

I have the following files

user.json

```
"user": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "nameuser",
  "online": true,
  "profile": {
    "photo": "",
    "validated": true,
    "popular": true,
    "suspect": false,
    "moderator": false,
    "age": "22 ani",
    "gender_id": "M"
  }
}
```

profile.raml

```
displayName: Profile
get:
  description: Get profile data
  queryParameters:
    userId:
      description: The user id for which we are requesting the profile data
      type: integer
      required: true
  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/json:
          example: |
            {
              "user": !include user.json,
              "details": {
                "friend": true
              }
            }
```

The user json is present in more examples and I want to reuse it.
I'm using [raml2html](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html) and it compiles it to 
[image]

so how do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used parameters successfully in the past. You will not be able to put a parameter inside an included file because RAML views all included files as strings. But you can do something like this in your profile.raml:

```
example: |
        {
          "user": <<userItem>>,
          "details": {
            "friend": true
          }
        }
```

The [RAML 200 Tutorial](http://raml.org/developers/raml-200-tutorial#parameters) has a good explanation and code examples (see snippets below) on how to declare parameters and them pass them in. I highly recommend reading the entire tutorial though.

```
resourceTypes:
  - collection:
       description: Collection of available <<resourcePathName>> in Jukebox.
       get:
         description: Get a list of <<resourcePathName>>.
         responses:
           200:
             body:
               application/json:
                 example: |
                   <<exampleCollection>>

/songs:
  type:
    collection:
      exampleCollection: !include jukebox-include-songs.sample
```